# The reference point of potential energy

Tags: newtonian-gravity, work, potential-energy, conventions, definition

In one dimension (I am not familiar with multivariable calculus), potential energy is defined as

$$E_p = -\int F \ dx$$

This is an indefinite integral, and the integration constant $C$ is involved when integrated. Also,

$$E_p = -\int_{x_0}^x F \ dx$$

and this is an indefinite integral as well - according to the fundamental theorem of calculus (the upper limit is a variable and the lower limit is a constant).

Let us, for example, consider the gravitational attraction given by $F=-\frac{GMm}{x^2}$.

My understanding is that for the differential equation $$-\frac{dE_p}{dx}=-\frac{GMm}{x^2}$$

the initial condition is **given** by (or set as) $E_p(\infty)=0$, and that leads to the integration constant being zero; we can substitute the initial condition into the following to check so:

$$-\int \frac{GMm}{x^2} dx = \frac{GMm}{x} + C$$

But my question is, in the definite integral definition of the potential energy, at the point $x=x_0$, the potential energy always becomes

$$E_p = -\int_{x_0}^{x_0} -\frac{GMm}{x^2} \ dx = 0$$

since the upper limit equals the lower limit.

Well, this is true because in our case we got $C=0$. But what I thought was, what if we set the initial condition, for example, as $E_p(\infty)=1$? Then $C$ becomes 1.

But still,

$$E_p = -\int_{x_0}^{x_0} -\frac{GMm}{x^2} \ dx = 0$$

holds true. This means the potential energy at the reference point is zero.

To be honest, I think the point where I am confused is **not** restricted to the case of the **reference point being infinity**, but for a general reference point $x_0$.

I am so confused; I have logical contradictions in my thoughts but can't identify what.

Comment: See http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/torsors.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a very simple case to understand the real thing. $$ \int x~ dx = \frac{x^2}{2} + C$$. All right? Now, lets integrate $x$ from 2 to a (a is any  variable, if I would have taken x it might have confused you) $$ \int_{2}^{a} x ~ dx = \left(\frac {x^2}{2} + C\right) \bigg|_{2}^{a}$$

$$\int_{2}^{a} x ~ dx = \left(a^2/2 + C \right)~-~ \left(2^2/2 + C\right)$$

$$\int_{2}^{a} x ~ dx = \frac{a^2}{2} + C - 2 - C $$

$$\int_{2}^{a} x ~ dx = \frac{a^2}{2} -2  $$ I want you to see that $$ \int_{2}^{a} x ~ dx = \frac{x^2}{2} \bigg|_{2}^{a} \\\\
\int_{2}^{a} x ~ dx = a^2/ 2 - 2^2/2 \\\\
\int_{2}^{a} x ~ dx = a^2/ 2 - 2 $$

Can you see that writing the constant of integration is redundant in the case of definite integrals or [definite indefinite integral](https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-006-calculus-revisited-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/part-ii-differentiation/lecture-11-the-definite-indefinite-integral)

Let's say that antiderivative of $f(x)$ is $F(x)+C$, then $$ \int_{\epsilon}^{x} f(x) dx = \left(F(x) + C\right) \bigg|_{\epsilon}^{x} \\\\
 \int_{\epsilon}^{x} f(x) dx = \left(F(x) + C\right) - \left(F(\epsilon) + C\right) \\\\ 
\int_{\epsilon}^{x} f(x) dx = F(x) + C - F(\epsilon) -C \\\\
\int_{\epsilon}^{x} f(x) dx = F (x) - F(\epsilon) $$  which is same as $$ \int_{\epsilon}^{x} f(x) dx = F(x) \bigg |_{\epsilon}^{x} $$ ($\epsilon$ is any fixed number).

Potential is defined as $$ V = -\int_{\mathcal{O}}^{x} \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{l}$$ where $\mathcal{O}$ is just any reference point where you know what the potential is and $\mathbf{E}$ is the force per unit mass/charge. For one dimension and point charge/mass the potential becomes easier to calculate $$ V(x) = - \int_{\mathcal{O}}^{x} \frac{k}{x^2} ~dx$$ where $k = G~M ~~\textrm{or} \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} Q$ 
$$V = \frac{k}{x} \bigg|_{\mathcal{O}}^{x} \\\\
V = \frac{k}{x} - \frac{k}{\mathcal{O}}$$ Now, if you take your reference point to be infinity then $$ V =  \frac{k}{x}$$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The integrals from $x_0$ to $x$ calculate the *difference* in potential energy between the points. This must be and is independent of any reference value $C$ you are free to choose arbitrarily. Note that those are definite integrals, because both boundaries are specified and no ambiguity in terms of an undetermined constant is present as it would for an indefinite integral.

Comment: $x$ is a variable to be chosen and $x_0$ is a constant. (reference point)

Comment: @curious Still a definite integral. Think of it as evaluating the integral for any given value of $x$. The point is that "indefinite integral" is synonymous to "stem-function" $F$ that is only determined up to a constant. Yet the integrals above - even if the upper boundary is a variable - are of the form $F(x) - F(x_0)$ and thus definite and independent of the specific choice of stem-function.

Comment: Have a look at fundamental theorem of calculus 1. It just states that such a function defined by the variable upper limit is an antiderivative.